# Pass checkbox 'checked' values to Submit function

Tags: jquery

For each element returned by

```
{! followers }
```

one checkbox is created. I have a submit button, and 'on Submit' I want to record which checkboxes are and are not checked.

```
<apex:repeat value="{! followers }" var="follower">
    $('#attendees').append(
        $('<div>').css('display','inline').append(
            $('<input>', {type:"checkbox"}).addClass('myCheckBox').attr('id', '{! follower.subscriberId }')
        ).append(
            $('<label>').text('{! follower.Subscriber.Name }')
        )
    );  
</apex:repeat>
```

How would I pass the values from these check boxes to the submit button? I just want to alert() or console.log() them once they reach the submit button.

Something like this maybe?

```
if ($('.myCheckBox').is(':checked')){
    alert($('.myCheckBox').attr(?))
};
```

Or this?

```
if ($('#attendees input').is(':checked')){
    alert($('#attendees input').attr('???'))
};
```

Comment: This is a question just about jQuery. Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099164/jquery-array-of-all-selected-checkboxes-by-class

Comment: Sorry, using Apex and Salesforce so my initial reaction was to come here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
var cbValues = $(".myCheckBox").map(function() {
    return this.checked;
}).get();

alert(cbValues);
```

Comment: mark your solution as "solved"

Comment: It takes 2 days before you can mark your own answer as correct.